# Strip query string from browser url without reloading page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I know there have been variations of this question asked a thousand times on stack overflow but none of them really relate to what I need to accomplish here.

I have a form that when submitted it adds a query string to the url after the page reloads.  I simply would like to know a way to remove this query string from the browser url WITHOUT reloading the page.

Currently with what I have below, a user will submit the form and the page reloads and has query string in the browser url then the below will run but it reloads the page for a second time.  How can I make it to where it won't reload 2 times but still strip the query string from the url?

```
window.location.href = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
```

Comment: Im sorry guys, I found my answer: http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers won't allow you to change the address programmatically without submitting the page. You could obfuscate it by using iframes on your page. The frame would then be loaded with content, but the URL would be that of the main page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for: 
`window.history.replaceState`

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page", ".");